# Load file name with spaces from FTP

Tags: php, xml, ftp, simplexml

I'm trying to load a xml file from an external ftp server. Sadly the filename contains a space between two words.

**Homepage-Filename Statistics-170210.xml**

I'm able to load the file with simplexml_load_file, if there is an underscore a dash. For example:

**Homepage-Filename_Statistics-170210.xml**

```
simplexml_load_file('ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.com/Homepage_Filename_Statistics-170210.xml');
```

But I'm not able to change the file name, so I have to load the file with spacing inside.

I have tried to replace the space with **%20** or backslash **/** , but it isn't working either. For example:

**Homepage_Filename%20Statistics-170210.xml**

or

**Homepage_Filename/ Statistics-170210.xml**

Someone has an idea, how load something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can also reproduce this problem with the `simplexml_load_file`.

Interestingly the `file_get_contents` works:

```
$url = 'ftp://username:password@ftp.domain.com/Homepage_Filename/ Statistics-170210.xml';
simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was searching for. Works like a charme. Thanks!